# ReactiveMongo/Play: `LastError: DatabaseException['<none>']`, while db still updates

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

weird problem: While my play application tries to insert/update records from some mongoDB collections while using reactivemongo, the operation seems to fail with a mysterious message, but the record does, actually, gets inserted/updated.

More info:

1. Insert to problematic collections from the mongo console works well
2. reading from all collections works well
3. reading and writing to other collections in the same db works well
4. writing to the problematic collections used to work.

Error message is:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[LastError: DatabaseException['<none>']]]
  at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
  at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
  at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
  at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
  at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
  at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
Caused by: reactivemongo.api.commands.LastError: DatabaseException['<none>']
```

Using ReactiveMongo 0.11.14, Play 2.5.4, Scala 2.11.7, MongoDB 3.4.0.

Thanks!

UPDATE - The mystery thickens!

Based on @Yaroslav_Derman's answer, I added a `.recover` clause, like so:

```
collectionRef.flatMap( c =>
  c.update( BSONDocument("_id" -> publicationWithId.id.get), publicationWithId.asInstanceOf[PublicationItem], upsert=true))
  .map(wr => {
    Logger.warn("Write Result: " + wr )
    Logger.warn("wr.inError: " + wr.inError)
    Logger.warn("*************")
    publicationWithId
  }).recover({
  case de:DatabaseException => {
    Logger.warn("DatabaseException: " + de.getMessage())
    Logger.warn("Cause: " + de.getCause())
    Logger.warn("Code: " + de.code)
    publicationWithId
  }
})
```

The recover clause does get called. Here's the log:

```
[info] application - Saving pub t3
[warn] application - *************
[warn] application - Saving publication     Publication(Some(BSONObjectID("5848101d7263468d01ff390d")),t3,2016-12-07,desc,auth,filename,None)
[info] application - Resolving database...
[info] application - Resolving database...
[warn] application - DatabaseException: DatabaseException['<none>']
[warn] application - Cause: null
[warn] application - Code: None
```

So no cause, no code, message is "`'<none>'`", but still an error. What gives?

I tried to move to 0.12, but that caused some compilation errors across the app, plus I'm not sure that would solve the problem. So I'd like to understand what's wrong first.

UPDATE #2:
Migrated to reactive-mongo 0.12.0. Problem persists.

Comment: Using 0.11.14, it's easy and recommended to upgrade to 0.12.0 : http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html

Comment: Thanks. I've upgraded to 0.12.0. Problem persists.

Comment: There is unsafe code in the sample, such as `.get` or `asInstanceOf`

Comment: Good point. It's safe, though, the id is set one line above it, and Publication extends PublicationItem. Problem persists even when I replace the unsafe code with safe one (by getting the required data before calling the update() method.

Comment: First try with a type safe code

Comment: It's type safe. Current line looks like this: "c.update( BSONDocument("_id" -> publicationId), BSONHandlers.PublicationItemWriter.write(publicationWithId), upsert=true)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved by downgrading to MongoDB 3.2.8. Turns out reactiveMongo 0.12.0 is **[not compatible with mongoDB 3.4](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html#compatibility)**.

Thanks everyone who looked into this.

Comment: As indicated on the 0.12 release notes, the compatibility for now is 2.6 up to 3.2 . As MongoDB 3.4 introduces some protocol incompatibilities, it will be supported in a future releases.

Comment: As for MongoDB 3.4, 0.12.1-SNAPSHOT can be tried: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/reactivemongo/reactivemongo_2.11/0.12.1-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: 0.12.1 has been released

Comment: @cchantep  can you confirm that 0.12.1 is NOT compatible with mongoDB 3.4.  Documentation states it is supported up to 3.2

Comment: @cchantep http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html#compatibility states: This release is compatible with the following runtime.

MongoDB from 2.6 up to 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

For play reactivemongo 0.12.0 you can do like this

```
def appsDb = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](DesktopApp.COLLECTION_NAME))

def save(id: String, user: User, body: JsValue) = {
    val version = (body \ "version").as[String]
    val app = DesktopApp(id, version, user)

    appsDb.flatMap(
      _.insert(app)
        .map(_ => app)
        .recover(processError)
    )
  }

def processError[T]: PartialFunction[Throwable, T] = {
    case ex: DatabaseException if ex.code.contains(10054 | 10056 | 10058 | 10107 | 13435 | 13436) =>
      //Custom exception which processed in Error Handler
      throw new AppException(ResponseCode.ALREADY_EXISTS, "Entity already exists")

    case ex: DatabaseException if ex.code.contains(10057 | 15845 | 16550) =>
      //Custom exception which processed in Error Handler
      throw new AppException(ResponseCode.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, "Entity not found")

    case ex: Exception =>
      //Custom exception which processed in Error Handler
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(ex.getMessage)
  }
```

Also you can add logs in `processError` method

Answer (score 1):

`LastError` was [deprecated in 0.11, replaced](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html) by `WriteResult`.

`LastError` does not, actually, means error, it could mean successful result, [you need to check](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/#reactivemongo.core.commands.LastError) `inError` property of the `LastError` object to detect if it's real error. As I see, the `'<none>'` error message give a good chance that this is not error.

Here is the example "how it was in 0.10": http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html